# How to use left join to have data in sibgle table from different table?

Tags: mysql

I am using a left join to get data into a single table with one query, I have done this for two different table and am now writing a single query to fetch data into a single one. My query is:

```
select ec.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as OUTLET,
       ollastsyncdatetime.TIMESTMP as LASTSYNCEDDATETIME,
       ollastindentdatetime.TIMESTMP as LASTINDENTDATETIME
from (ollastsyncdatetime 
      left join ollastindentdatetime on ((ollastsyncdatetime.OUTLET = ollastindentdatetime.OUTLET))) 
Inner Join ecustomer ec on ollastsyncdatetime.outlet = ec.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER 
group by ollastsyncdatetime.OUTLET
```

This query is giving me a result like this:

[image: query result]

I am able to join two tables but facing issues in joining more than two.
Now I have 2 more tables in my Database from which I have to fetch data and make new columns
the two new tables are

1. ollastdumpdamagedatetime

[image: this is the table]

2. ollastindentdatetime

[image: this the table 2]

I want a result like this:

[image: resultant table]

If there is no data in table it should show blank because I am populating columns data on the comparison with outlets. Please ignore the actual data in table; they are same because I am using this as an example only.

Answer (score 1):

Use left join for both table

```
select ec.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as OUTLET,ollastsyncdatetime.TIMESTMP as LASTSYNCEDDATETIME,ollastindentdatetime.TIMESTMP as LASTINDENTDATETIME 
from ollastsyncdatetime left join ollastindentdatetime 
on ollastsyncdatetime.OUTLET = ollastindentdatetime.OUTLET 
left Join ecustomer ec 
on ollastsyncdatetime.outlet = ec.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER
```

Comment: it is giving me only 3 columns not  all five

Comment: @could you please add your 3 tables sample data in your question

Comment: actually i have  got the idea from your answer ...now i ll try by my own. :)